# Combine SED commands

Tags: sed

What is the best way to combine these two SED commands together? The first command searches for CSP and then moves down one line. The second command puts a semicolon in column 3.

```
sed -ne '/CSP/{n;p;}' test1>test2
sed 's/./;/3' test2>final
```

The command is needed to act upon one line of data and cannot be conducted separately.

Comment: I just need to know in general how to add two commands together.

Comment: Doesn't the first one print the line following one with `CSP`? I think you've already combined two commands, the `n` and `p`. So would simply `sed -ne '/CSP/{n;s/./;/3;p;}'` work?

Comment: ilkkachu is right. At a minimum you should avoid the temp file by using pipes: `sed -ne '...' test1 | sed '...' > final`

Comment: @ilkkachu make it an answer and get reputation for it!

Comment: I'll yield under the social pressure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, `sed` commands can be put together separated either with newlines or with semicolons. A bit like in sh or python, actually. (Most `sed` commands, that is, some require the newline.)

So, to put `n`, `p` and `s` together, you can just use semicolons, like you already did with `{n;p}` in the first command. The full command in this case would be:

```
sed -ne '/CSP/{n;s/./;/3;p;}' test1 > final
```

Or you could write it with newlines instead:

```
sed -ne '/CSP/{n
s/./;/3
p
}' test1 > final
```

But that's a bit annoying to do on the command line for a simple one-liner (and apparently even harder in `csh`), but might be more useful in case you save a `sed` script to a file.

Comment: Good job ilkkachu!

Comment: GNU `sed` accepts `;` as a command separator. BSD `sed` (as found on OS X, for example) requires newlines.

Comment: @Kusalananda, `;` can be used to separate most commands in all sed implementations, but cannot be used after certain commands like `:`, `b`, `}`, `w` or `#` in some implementations. For instance `b a;b` is meant to branch to the `a;b` label in POSIX `sed`s (that will change in the next POSIX spec  version though), and in `# foo; bar`, that `;` is part of the comment in all implementations, even GNU `sed` (same for `w file;foo.txt`). `sed -ne '/CSP/{n;s/./;/3;p;}'` should work in all `sed` implementations even if IIRC POSIX currently doesn't allow it (a bug in the spec)

Comment: I did test that example with the `sed` on OS X, actually, since I expected there was some trickery with the semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that removing some of the parameters helped when I had to use larger files and leave more of the file contents intact. I am answering this in case anyone looks this up in the future.

```
sed '/CSP /{n;s/./;/3;}' test1>test2
```

Comment: Without the `-n`, that would print the `CSP` line though.